# Embedding a Windows Form into a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I have a Old windows form application and i don't want to convert it to wpf , i want to embed it inside my wpf application main window . How can i do this ?.

Also , How Can i transfer text between wpf and embeded WinForm using WindowsFormHost ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll want to use a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx). Check [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/mixing-wpf-and-winforms/) tutorial out (shows how to do WPF in WinForms and vice versa).

Comment: Can i transfer data between wpf and embeded WinForm using WindowsFormHost ?

Comment: @rajat - Yes.  `WindowsFormHost` works just like a `UserControl` of course it sounds like it would be fair easier just to convert your application.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `WindowsFormsHost` to add single Forms into an WPF application. If this is enough for your purposes have a look at this [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx).