# How to instantiate a Datagridview(in code behind)

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, wpf-controls

I am actually using a datagrid which is filled by a datatable to display my data(NOTE: These are dynamic data).
Till now I was proceeding as below

```
  grid = new Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
```

My datatable as

```
 table = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

and I fill the datagrid with the datatable by doing

```
   grid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

However Due to dificulties I am facing to delete a column etc of the datagrid,I want to move to Datagridview instead of the datagrid.

I tried

```
 grid = new Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridview();  //WRONG
```

But it is aparently not the correct way.

How do I do this?

NOTE:
Framework 3.5 / WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use native Winforms DataGridView in WPF? If yes, you should use WindowFormsHost and place DataGriView inside it.
BTW, did you tried rebinding the datagrid after removing the column from your bound table? I am very sure that rebinding or restting the 'ItemsSource' should work.

Comment: Yes i tried but The data of the column is being deleted but my header names are dynamic,and the header is not deleted hence i am left with an empty column with header-i had posted the problem here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516083/removing-a-column-from-a-data-table-that-was-dynamically-created?noredirect=1#comment30672114_20516083)

Comment: Let me try this. Perhaps, looks a issue with layout update. I will get back to you asap.

Answer (score 1):

see [Embedding a Windows Form into a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850404/embedding-a-windows-form-into-a-wpf-application) - if you want use WindowsForms controls.

But the right way is using MVVM http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial (if you use wpf)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the solution that suited me for future visitors.
I found the answer to ALL my problems on this post >>HERE:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/using-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf/