# Casting of WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, casting, wpf-controls

I am using WindowsFormHost so as to be able to use a gridview in my WPF application
(started with this ,[How to instantiate a Datagridview(in code behind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537916/how-to-instantiate-a-datagridviewin-code-behind/20538144?noredirect=1#comment30711373_20538144)).

And proceeded as

```
 public WindowsFormsHost HOST = new WindowsFormsHost();
```

my gridview as

```
 System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView gridview = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
```

(do not forget the references, follow here- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/using-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf/)

I fill it with a datatable as

```
 table = new System.Data.DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Object ID");
            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(column);

            }
            foreach (string row in rows)
            { 
                drow = table.NewRow();
                tit = row.Substring(0, row.IndexOf('$'));
                drow[0] = tit.IndexOf('&') > -1 ? tit.Substring(tit.IndexOf('&') + 1) : tit;
                table.Rows.Add(drow);

            }

            //making the native control known to the WPF application
            HOST.Child = gridview;
            //Displaying the column headers of the listbox(assigned above). 
            gridview.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
```

However when I add the gridview to my WPF window as

```
  this.Children.Add(gridview);   //error at this line
```

I get an error saying

```
 cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to 'System.Windows.UIElement'
```

Why so ?
I mean what may I do to rectify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I am posting what did the trick for me for future visitors.
Instead of adding the gridview I added the HOST to the window and it worked.

```
 this.Children.Add(HOST);
```

SOLVED HERE :[Using windows forms controls on a WPF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603775/using-windows-forms-controls-on-a-wpf-page/20603820?noredirect=1#20603820)

Answer (score 1):

`DataGridView` is a `WinForms` control. So you can't directly add that to WPF Control's child. Instead add the `WindowsFormsHost` instance as follows:

```
RootGrid.Children.Add(HOST);
```

Comment: What is RootGrid ? My IDE does not recognises it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this question and current answer serious??? Why on earth would you want to import the WindowsForms dll and add a CPU intensive `WindowsFormsHost` element to your WPF application just so that you can use a `DataGridView` control? You'll find that it's much better just using the equivalent WPF control: `DataGrid`

You can find out all about the `DataGrid` class by viewing the [`DataGrid` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. This page has a detailed description and code examples to help you to use the control. Furthermore, the [WPF DataGrid Practical Examples](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples) page on CodeProject has detailed examples on how to do just about anything that one might want to do with the `DataGrid` control.

Comment: Maybe he already has a lot of code that populates the DataGridView and doesn't want to rewrite it all.

Comment: Sheridan , I am actually using the DATAGRID itself.However, I am populating my column headers dynamically(in a for each loop) and then adding the rows(in another for each loop).Now the reason for which I want to  use a datagridview is because I am having problems to delete a particular column of the datagrid. Do you have any suggestion to this ?