# Using windows forms controls on a WPF page

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, wpf-controls, type-conversion

Guys I need a datagridview on a WPF page.

I used this

```
public WindowsFormsHost HOST = new WindowsFormsHost();
```

Then instanttiated my datagridview as

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView gridview = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
```

Then using a datatable I filled the datagrid view as

//making the native control known to the WPF application

```
HOST.Child = gridview;
    //Displaying the column headers  (from datatable). 
gridview.DataSource = table.DefaultView;
```

However when I add the gridview to my WPF window as

```
this.Children.Add(gridview);   //error at this line
```

I get an error saying

```
cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' to 'System.Windows.UIElement
```

Why so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add 'HOST' to WPF Window rather than adding 'gridview'.

```
   this.Children.Add(HOST);
```