# Setting fontsize of a datagridview using an Double

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, font-size

I managed to use a datagridview in a WPF application(how? answer:[Using windows forms controls on a WPF page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603775/using-windows-forms-controls-on-a-wpf-page/20603820?noredirect=1#20603820))

Now I want to know how to set any font size of this datagridview.

NOTE: I have a variable of type Double that contains the size i want to set.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the documentation of [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), especially at properties starting with the letter `F`?

Comment: Note, that coordinates/sizes in WPF are expressed in terms of DPI. WPF works internally with a resolution of 96 DPI (which means that 96 pixels would cover an inch). To use such a WPF pixel value in WinForms, you would need to calculate its absolute pixel value factoring in the DPI settings of the system. (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings) about how to get the system DPI settings)

Comment: remove that horrible dinosaur winforms crap from WPF. WPF does not care about dinosaur winforms, use regular standard WPF controls which are WAY better and allow much richer UI and functionality.

Comment: @HighCore , i was having problem with the WPF datagrid(in the context of MY project) that is why I needed to implement this dinosaur.

Comment: @AnoushkaSeechurn in that case you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) here. Instead of asking about your attempted solution, ask about your real problem behind it. So ask about the WPF datagrid, not the winforms stuff.